# on('click') function fires on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have a problem, I got an `li` that toggles whenever an element is clicked, but the problem is that I'm trying to navigate the window to center that `li` when the "click" element was click. It's working but my problem is, that script only works on the second click?

My theory is that since that `li` is in `display:none`, it's not reading it on first click, rather on the second click. Is there anyway to solve this in a way that it will fire up the toggle plus the window navigation at the same time?

And also is there a way to move it dynamically(animate) in a smooth way?

Thanks guys!

[**SAMPLE JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xFcLv/)

```
 $(document).on('click', "#click", function(){

  var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
      foo = $('ul li:nth-child(2)'),
      elHeight = foo.height(),
      elOffset = foo.offset();
  $(window).scrollTop(elOffset.top + (elHeight/2) - (viewportHeight/2));
  $(foo).slideToggle();
  });
```

Comment: Always put the relevant markup **in** the question, not just hidden away in a fiddle.

Comment: The second child `li` is overlapping the first.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry I just missed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe do all other manipulations after the `slideToggle` has completed? http://jsfiddle.net/xFcLv/8/

Comment: The click performs perfectly with you code. Can you explain more what issue you exactly have?

Comment: its working on single click

Answer (score 0):

first mate try to set it visibility: hidden; not display none

if not work too, try to set timer work when you click directly, this time will be call a calculate function again ... and its will be work .. to can test it more easy .. add this to under your function ..

```
        $(document).on("mousemove", "#click", function(){

  var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
      foo = $("ul li:nth-child(2)"),
      elHeight = foo.height(),
      elOffset = foo.offset();
  $(window).scrollTop(elOffset.top + (elHeight/2) - (viewportHeight/2));
  $(foo).slideToggle();
  });
```